# implementation of elf packer for shared libraries on aarch64

Tags: security, gcc, elf, arm64

I had implemented an elf packer for executable for aarch64.
Now, I would like to pack a shared library.

For executable binaries, the entry point is replaced with the address
of the loader. While the job of the loader is to decrypt the .text section
and finally jump to the decrypted .text section.

However, there is no entry point for shared libraries.
Where should my loader be placed ?

Comment: Not familiar with ELF, but you could compile a C function with `__attribute__((constructor))` and see what that does.

Answer (score 0):

The elf loader can be triggered by patching the entry of .rela.dyn with the address of the loader.

https://github.com/0xN3utr0n/Noteme/blob/master/injection.c

This trick has been tested on x86_64 and x86_86.
But failed on aarch64.